# Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)) Adding Active Directory Account

Tags: c#, active-directory, ws-federation

This question has been asked several times, but so far I have not seen an answer that looks anything like our problem.

Firstly we have two duplicate environments. Both running Windows 2012 R2 servers with Active Directory for use with our Active Directory Federated Service.

Our system comprises of a web portal that communicates via WCF services. From this we have a security WCF service that allows us to create new AD accounts. This currently works perfectly on our dev and test machines (althought these use the same AD and ADFS machines), but in our production environment when we call the same function to create a new user we get the following error:

> 02:07:24 [17] ERROR UserService !!! ERROR !!!
>       System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by     the target of an invocation. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is     denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>         at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] args)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.SetPassword(DirectoryEntry de, String newPassword)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.SetPassword(AuthenticablePrincipal p, String newPassword)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.InsertPrincipal(Principal p, StoreCtx storeCtx, GroupMembershipUpdater updateGroupMembership, NetCred credentials, AuthenticationTypes authTypes, Boolean needToSetPassword)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.Insert(Principal p)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.Save()
>      at UserService.Implementation.LDAPManager.CreateUser(String logon, String firstName, String lastName, String userPassword, String EmailAddress) in e:\Bld\1\User Service\UserService\Implementation\LDAPManager.cs:line 60
>      at UserService.createNewUser(NewUserValueObject newUser) in e:\Bld\1\User Service\UserService\UserService.cs:line 127

As I have stated we have looked at the AD side and cannot find anything obvious, but I am sure that you great op's and dev's will soon tell me otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what account the service is running as and it's permissions. I recently had a similar issue trying to run a service as a group managed service account, and the service account did not have access to add/remove computers from the domain. Had to delegate access to the group managed service account's controlling security group.

The following article is a pretty good reference:

https://richardstk.com/2013/11/29/create-a-dedicated-account-to-join-computers-to-a-domain/

To avoid create SPN's for the service account's I needed to manage the various OU's, I just threw them into a security group of their own and delegated access based on the security group. Mileage may vary here, depending on your situation and whether or not you are using service account's to run your service.